# The same function always returns different answers for the same input

Tags: rust

I've been doing exercises after [Rust Books's Chapter 8](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-00-common-collections.html).
I've implemented the first task, but there is a problem: I don't change the function and the input, but the result is always different.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}",vector(&mut vec![10,15,20,20]));
    println!("{:?}",vector(&mut vec![10,15,20,20]));
    println!("{:?}",vector(&mut vec![10,15,20,20]));
    println!("{:?}",vector(&mut vec![10,15,20,20]));
}

fn vector(V:&mut Vec<i32>)->[i32;3]{
    let average:i32 = V.iter().sum::<i32>()/(V.len() as i32);
    V.sort();
    let median:i32 = V[V.len()/2+1];
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    let mut mode = 0;
    for el in V{
        let count = map.entry(el).or_insert(0);
        //or_insert returns reference to the value of the key
        *count+=1; //dereference and increase;
      }
      for (k,v) in map{
          if v>mode{
                mode=*k;
          }
      }

    return [average,median,mode]
}
```

The outputs vary from execution to execution:

```
[16, 20, 20]
[16, 20, 15]
[16, 20, 15]
[16, 20, 20]
```

Here's a [playground runnable example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4b87476374b066629e00756a2cafd090)

Why does the output differ from the same input values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you assign `*k` to `mode` does not make sense, did you mean to assign `v`? It seems like at a minimum this needs to be:

```
let mut mode = (0, 0);
for (k, v) in map {
    if v > mode.1 {
        mode = (*k, v);
    }
}

return [average, median, mode.0];
```

The reason your code is behaving non-deterministically is because hashmaps do not make any guarantees about the order in which the key/value pairs are produced by the iterator. On [the docs page you mentioned](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-03-hash-maps.html) for instance, it notes

> This code will print each pair in an arbitrary order:

and because your code as-is uses `v` instead of `*k` for the first check (and `v` is a small value compared to `*k`, the first value to be produced by the hashmap will a *always* be set as the `mode` value because the the first entry is larger than the default `0` mode, and then future pairs are never large enough to change it.

Comment: @loganfsmyth, thank you so much, this works!
But i still don't really understand why I can't just assign the key of the HashMap (the string that represents the key) to the mode variable (so that the value of mode == key)

Comment: Your `if` compares the `v` to the `mode` and your assignment writes `k` to `mode` so with your code as it was, you end up comparing the key of the first pair with the value of the second pair, which logically does not make sense.